# Neo4J HA with Neo4J Spatial

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-spatial

So I have just set up an HA environment where I have a master server and instances of an application using Neo4J embedded talking to that cluster.  Everything seems to work if the state of both databases is the same.

However if I delete all data from my slave instance, and have it join the cluster, I expect the data from the cluster to propagate into the slave instance.  Instead I get errors with what appears to be Neo4J spatial.  I have Neo4J spatial in my application, and the server plugin installed in the on the master server side.

An example of the stack trace I get:

`2015-10-19 15:10:27.096+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Exception when stopping org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Delegate@ae93556 org.neo4j.gis.spatial.indexprovider.SpatialIndexImplementation.stop()V
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.neo4j.gis.spatial.indexprovider.SpatialIndexImplementation.stop()V
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.Lifecycles$1.stop(Lifecycles.java:55)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Delegate.stop(Lifecycle.java:75)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:527)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:185)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.stop(NeoStoreDataSource.java:1160)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:527)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.stop(DataSourceManager.java:137)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.cluster.SwitchToSlave.stopServicesAndHandleBranchedStore(SwitchToSlave.java:521)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.cluster.SwitchToSlave.checkDataConsistency(SwitchToSlave.java:357)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.cluster.SwitchToSlave.executeConsistencyChecks(SwitchToSlave.java:316)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.cluster.SwitchToSlave.switchToSlave(SwitchToSlave.java:219)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.cluster.HighAvailabilityModeSwitcher$2.run(HighAvailabilityModeSwitcher.java:328)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.NamedThreadFactory$2.run(NamedThreadFactory.java:99)
2015-10-19 15:10:27.102+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Lifecycle exception Failed to transition component 'org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Delegate@ae93556' from STOPPED to SHUTTING_DOWN. Please see attached cause exception
org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to transition component 'org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Delegate@ae93556' from STOPPED to SHUTTING_DOWN. Please see attached cause exception
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:559)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:200)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.stop(NeoStoreDataSource.java:1160)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:527)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.stop(DataSourceManager.java:137)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.cluster.SwitchToSlave.stopServicesAndHandleBranchedStore(SwitchToSlave.java:521)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.cluster.SwitchToSlave.checkDataConsistency(SwitchToSlave.java:357)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.cluster.SwitchToSlave.executeConsistencyChecks(SwitchToSlave.java:316)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.cluster.SwitchToSlave.switchToSlave(SwitchToSlave.java:219)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.cluster.HighAvailabilityModeSwitcher$2.run(HighAvailabilityModeSwitcher.java:328)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.NamedThreadFactory$2.run(NamedThreadFactory.java:99)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.neo4j.gis.spatial.indexprovider.SpatialIndexImplementation.shutdown()V
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.Lifecycles$1.shutdown(Lifecycles.java:64)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Delegate.shutdown(Lifecycle.java:81)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:555)
    ... 18 more
2015-10-19 15:10:27.103+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Chained lifecycle exception Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Delegate@ae93556' failed to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Delegate@ae93556' failed to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:532)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:185)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.stop(NeoStoreDataSource.java:1160)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:527)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.stop(DataSourceManager.java:137)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.cluster.SwitchToSlave.stopServicesAndHandleBranchedStore(SwitchToSlave.java:521)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.cluster.SwitchToSlave.checkDataConsistency(SwitchToSlave.java:357)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.cluster.SwitchToSlave.executeConsistencyChecks(SwitchToSlave.java:316)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.cluster.SwitchToSlave.switchToSlave(SwitchToSlave.java:219)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.cluster.HighAvailabilityModeSwitcher$2.run(HighAvailabilityModeSwitcher.java:328)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.NamedThreadFactory$2.run(NamedThreadFactory.java:99)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.neo4j.gis.spatial.indexprovider.SpatialIndexImplementation.stop()V
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.Lifecycles$1.stop(Lifecycles.java:55)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Delegate.stop(Lifecycle.java:75)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:527)
    ... 19 more`

Does Neo4j Spatial support replication across instances?  Or more specifically restoring the spatial index to a new empty instance that joins the cluster for the first time?

Comment: This looks like a versioning issue. Please make sure that you're version of Neo4j and the Spatial extension fit together.

Comment: So I am using Neo4J 2.2.5 and version 0.14-neo4j-2.2.3 for neo4j spatial.  I tried to put 0.14-neo4j-2.2.5 spatial on both the master and in my application but I get the same error.   This is only when I have an empty application joining an existing cluster.  If both master and slave are empty, or both master and slave have the same database, it seems to work just fine.

Comment: I guess it's worth filing an issue with Neo4j spatial for this: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial/issues/new

Comment: Submitting a ticket.  Should note that I just stood up another Neo4J server instance.  I get the same issue when creating another Neo4J server but is empty.  When I restart the server,  the server starts but spatial indexes are not copied over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update to Neo4j spatial to version 0.15-neo4j-2.2.6 fixes this issue.  So you need to be using Neo4j 2.2.6 in order to have Spatial indexes replicate properly